# difference between (String)value and value.toString() , new Long(value) and (Long)value

Tags: java, casting

In some places i saw `(String)value`.In some places `value.toString()`

What is the difference between these two.In which scenario which one i need to use.

And what is the difference between    `new Long(value)` and `(Long)value`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(String) value casts object value to string, which has to extends String. value.toString() calls method on object value, which is inherritated from class Object and this method return String, that show information of this object. If you have some yourClass value, it is reccomended to overrite toString()

new Long(value) creates new object of type Long and sets value of Long to your variable value. (Long)value get object value and cast it to object of type Long. in Long(value) value has to be number or string.

Comment: Can you extend Long? I thought it was a sealed class in Java.

Comment: what is **value to value** ?

Comment: ah it is, I forgot.. sets value of Long to value - your variable :D

Comment: "in Long(value) value has to be number." It can be String also. Read the API.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
new Long(value)
```

creates new  wrapper class Object

and

```
(Long)value
```

type cast value to Long( to wrapper) if possible.

similarly

```
String(value)
```

type cast value to to String

but toString() is a method which is a object class method and One must override it according to need, eg.

```
class User
{
String name;
int age;

public String toString()
{
return "name :"+name+" \n  age :"+age;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In no language (that I know of) will a cast change the type of an object.

You use the cast `(String)` when you have, say, a reference that the compiler thinks is an Object, but you know is really a String, and you want the compiler to know that.  If you have an Integer and try to cast to String you will get a ClassCastException when you run the code.

So if you have an Integer and want its String representation you'd use toString.

(Note that a cast WILL change the type of a "scalar".  Ie, you can cast from int to char with `(char)` and the compiler will perform the appropriate conversion.  The "cast" in this case is an entirely different concept.  It's unfortunate that tradition has led the same syntax to be used for both.)

Answer (score 2):

When you cast an object to String you are sure that it is a string and at run-time if it happens to be an instance of another object then you get a class cast exception.

On the other hand, When you call a toString() method on an object it need not be a string as all classes inherit that method from class object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , is value a string itself?
the (String)value is a cast and will only work is value is a string.
However, calling value.toString() is just a method call. toString() is a method
of every object in java, so that will not fail even if value is, let's say, an integer.

Now , Calling (Long)value is trying to cast value to Long, and will only work
if value is of type Long.
and, calling Long(value) is actually calling the constructor of class Long,
passing in value as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

`String` class implements `CharSequence` and also it extends from `Object` class. So if somebody is using other type of `CharSequence` we have to typecast like your first version `(String)value` 
*[ `(String)value` if it contains `String` object and `(StringBuffer)value` for StringBuffer type of object]*
About `toString()` we have to override `toString()` method in our class which will show our object representation in String format as per our requirement. If we don't override then default implementation of `toString()` from `Object`class will be inherited and will give the String in hexadecimal representation of the hash code of our object like `UserObject@12dacd1`

Other implementation of `CharSequence` are **CharBuffer, StringBuffer, StringBuilder**

1> **(String)value** means `value` contains String object. If it doesn't contain `String` the `ClassCastException` will be thrown at runtime. Typecasting will throw compile time exception if you typecast with irrelevant type hierarchy. like given below

```
Exception e = new Exception();
String str = (String)e;
```

2> Invoking **toString()** means `anyobject`  is not necessary to be a `String` object. Proper overriding `toString()` method in our own class will be helpful for the String representation of our own class and also it will **never** throw any exception exists in the java world because it inherits `toString()` from object class. So if your override **toString** and you print `System.out.println(userObject);` then it will not show  hexadecimal representation of the hash code of our object like `UserObject@12dacd1`

```
public class UserObject {
    String name;
    int age;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " Name="+name+" \n age="+age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserObject uo = new UserObject();
        uo.name="AAA";
        uo.age=18;
        System.out.println(uo); //output will be "Name=AAA age=18" instead of "UserObject@12dacd1"

    }
}
```

About new Long(value) and (Long)value.

`new Long(value)` means, you have got value as `long/String` you want to convert it into wrapper class `Long` object. So you can use Long(long), Long(String) [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#constructor_summary) as per the condition.

Long typecasting explanation is  similar to above String typecasting or any typecasting. `(Long)value`  means when you get the code like below then you can typecast to Long, Integer, Double as well depends on the assigned value at the right side of the equal symbol.

```
Number i=10L; //java.lang.Number
Long a= (Long)i;
```

Comment: You said 'if somebody is using other type of `CharSequence` we have to typecast', but be careful. You cannot cast a `StringBuilder` to a `String` for example, in the same way you can't cast an `Integer` to a `Long`

Comment: That won't work. In `Number i = 10`, 10 is an `int`, and gets boxed to `Integer`. `Integer` cannot be cast to `Long`. The compiler will not unbox i just to rebox it to `Long`.  Also, prefer `Long.valueOf(long)`  to calling a constructor yourself.

Comment: Very confused answer, and several outright errors. CharSequence is completely irrelevant. You don't have to override toString(). The existence of a typecast does not imply that the object is of the correct type.  -1

Comment: @EJP Opps! Thanks for your input. It means I am under wrong impression because of that I gave such answer. May I know what is possible correct answer except `accepted` answer? Can you help me to refer a link to understand this concept? Or you can post this concept so that I will  understand it more.

Answer (score -1):

Those are all very different. The first one is `Type Casting`. Let's say that you receive an Object on your method, and you know it's a String, so you want it to be referred to as that type. so you do that

```
public void method(Object obj){
    String str = (String) obj;
}
```

The [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method is one inherited from [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class, that returns to you a `String` representation of any given `Object`.

So the difference is, when you do the casting, your object must already be a `String`, there is no actual conversion. The difference is that you can use a more specific type for your variable,  but when you invoke toString that is not necessary.

Invoking `toString` may give you a different object than the original one, unless your class is already a `String`, in that case the same reference is returned.

Comment: Calling `toString()` does not necessarily create a new object, though it hardly matters. After `String s = ...; String t = s.toString();` s and t should be the same object.

Comment: Yes I see your point. You're considering the String pool. What I meant by that is that the return of the method isn't the exact same object, as it is in typecasting. I'll try and edit the answer to make it more clear

Comment: Strings are immutable, so there's no reason for the `toString` method to copy one. I'm pretty sure String's implementation is `public String toString() { return this; }`.

Comment: @EricJablow, I said that in my answer. I said that in Strings the same reference is returned

Comment: May I ask the *downvoters* why the negative mark? Please leave a comment explaining a reason.

Comment: Probably because they think you should have done more research yourself.

Comment: More research on what? Is anything that I said incorrect or out of the scope of the question?

Answer (score -1):

when you do "(String)value" it's a casting, in other words, you is explicitly "saying" for compiler that value is a string, but if not, will throw a runtime exception.

when you do "value.ToString()" will be create a new string with the this value

the same goes for Long

Comment: Do String.toString() really create NEW string?

Comment: Yes. Strings are immutable. Have you checked what String.toString() method is doing. Is it creating NEW string.

Comment: there should be a check to return himself, without creating a new string